# Render a div in React with an initial scroll on SSR

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll, server-side-rendering

I have a mobile SSR Application and React component which is rendering a free scroll horizontal div with images. However I want this div to be rendered such that it's initially scrolled at the position which displays for example 3rd image in the middle of the screen.

Is there any way to achieve it with SSR on first paint, before hydration, mounting, hooks execution?

```
const ImageViewer = ({ images }) => {
useLayoutEffect(() => {
 window.scrollIntoView(images[3].id)
});

return (
<div>
{images.map(img => <div id={img.id}>
<img src={img.src} height='100' width='100' />
</div>}
</div>
)
}
```

This would somewhat work for a non-SSR effect of getting to the 3rd image's position, but I'd like the same without having to wait for CSR.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.